# Application layer firewall on UNIX machines

Tags: firewall

https://subgraph.com/img/screenshots/FirewallDetailed.png

**Question**: what is the application layer firewall solution that can bee seen on the screenshot?

Screenshot is from Subgraph OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is this one:
https://github.com/subgraph/fw-daemon.
Since Subgraph is a distribution with focus on security and just ships with an app level firewall.